# Check if a component is a child of another in React

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have the following situation where I need to do some logic (e.g. position children in relation to the parent, etc.).

Is there a way to have parent child relationships in React between nested components being able to reference one another?

For example:

```
  <Surface color="red" size={100}
    <h1>HELLO</h1>

    <Surface color="black" size={50}>
      <h1>World</h1>
    </Surface>
  </Surface>
```

Since the nested `Surface` is inside of another `Surface`, I'd like the child to be mounted (or some other logic) to the parent. I know that I can simply traverse from the root and build out that tree, where if a Surface containers another Surface as a child, then do the logic I'm looking for, but that seems quite awful....

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer to this? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can alias the parent Surface using "ref" and then access it in Child Surface.

But this is highly discouraged to use "ref" in a class's render method. You can define any public method on your component classes and call them through refs. In most cases, it's clearer to use the built-in React data flow instead of using refs imperatively.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use `ref` and ensure I have unique names across these components, but with many of these spread across an app, I really can't do this... I wish there was a way that if one component sits within another, I can capture that and do some logic....

Comment: Why don't you make a composite component and put it in a function and then give it an alias if needed. That way you'll decrease the number of refs and also you can increase reusability. But to answer your question, I can't think of any other way to achieve this.

Comment: what do you mean by a composite component? a higher order component?

Comment: A component consisting other primitive/non-primitive components.

Comment: Yes, if I read that correctly, `Surface` is a composite component. I still don't know how this could help this problem.

Answer (score -2):

you can use react-redux which is best way to manage your components sate in a centralized location known as store.
You can search about react-redux
[example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know about `redux` and `react-redux` but I don't see how it would be useful to me. I need to know parent child relationships between these components so I can mount children to their appropriate parent. I'm basically trying to build a scene graph or tree with parent/child relationship.